# Why aren't my variables working in the while loop

Tags: pygame

for some reason when i blit my image and try to move my cube, it doesn't work and my text doesn't work either.

```
import pygame
from random import randint

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Cube game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
TP_usage = 0
FPS = 60
Cube_Vel = 4
HP = 3

CubeX = 400
CubeY = 400

TP_staff = pygame.image.load("Game imag/TP staff.png")
TP_staff_rect = TP_staff.get_rect(center=(randint(10, 500), (randint(10, 770))))

No_tp_text = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
No_tp_Warning = No_tp_text.render("NO TP USAGE", False, "white")

TP_usage_Stat_Font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
TP_usage_Stat = TP_usage_Stat_Font.render(f"TP usages: {TP_usage}", False, "white")

Cube_player = pygame.image.load("Game imag/Cube.png")
Cube_player_rect = Cube_player.get_rect(center=(CubeX, CubeY))

while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    #part that is not updating 
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(TP_usage_Stat, (500, 600))
    screen.blit(Cube_player, Cube_player_rect)
    screen.blit(TP_staff, TP_staff_rect)

    if Cube_player_rect.colliderect(TP_staff_rect):
        TP_usage += 1
        print(TP_usage)

    if TP_usage > 1:
        TP_usage = 1
        print(TP_usage)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and CubeX - Cube_Vel > 0:
        CubeX -= Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and CubeX + Cube_Vel < WIDTH:
        CubeX += Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and CubeY - Cube_Vel > 0:
        CubeY -= Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and CubeY + Cube_Vel < HEIGHT:
        CubeY += Cube_Vel

    pressed_keys = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if (pressed_keys[0]) and TP_usage > 0:
        TP_usage -= 1
        print(TP_usage)
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        CubeX = mx
        CubeY = my
    if (pressed_keys[0]) and TP_usage < 0:
        screen.blit(No_tp_Warning, (400, 500))

    pygame.display.update()
```

before i had it something like this

```
import pygame
from random import randint

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Cube game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
TP_usage = 0
PhoX = 100
PhoY = -200
FPS = 60
Cube_Vel = 4
HP = 3

CubeX = 400
CubeY = 400

TP_staff = pygame.image.load("Game imag/TP staff.png")

TP_usage_Stat_Font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
TP_usage_Stat = TP_usage_Stat_Font.render(f"TP usages: {TP_usage}", False, "white")

Cube_player = pygame.image.load("Game imag/Cube.png")
# Timer
obstacle_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(obstacle_timer, 5000)
TP_staff_rect = TP_staff.get_rect(center=(randint(10, 500), (randint(10, 770))))

game_on = True

while True:

    No_tp_text = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

    No_tp_Warning = No_tp_text.render("NO TP USAGE", False, "white")

    Cube_player_rect = Cube_player.get_rect(center=(CubeX, CubeY))
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(TP_usage_Stat, (500, 600))
    screen.blit(Cube_player, Cube_player_rect)
    screen.blit(TP_staff, TP_staff_rect)

    if event.type == obstacle_timer:
        TP_staff_rect = TP_staff.get_rect(center=(randint(10, 500), (randint(10, 770))))

    if Cube_player_rect.colliderect(TP_staff_rect):
        TP_usage += 1
        print(TP_usage)

    if TP_usage > 1:
        TP_usage = 1
        print(TP_usage)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and CubeX - Cube_Vel > 0:
        CubeX -= Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and CubeX + Cube_Vel < WIDTH:
        CubeX += Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and CubeY - Cube_Vel > 0:
        CubeY -= Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and CubeY + Cube_Vel < HEIGHT:
        CubeY += Cube_Vel

    pressed_keys = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if (pressed_keys[0]) and TP_usage > 0:
        TP_usage -= 1
        print(TP_usage)
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        CubeX = mx
        CubeY = my
    if (pressed_keys[0]) and TP_usage < 0:
        screen.blit(No_tp_Warning, (400, 500))

    pygame.display.update()
```

the problem was it was going everywhere 60 times a sec so i tried to move the staff rect out of the while loop and then everything else as will but now nothing is updating like normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game updates normally. The problem is that you move with Cube_player and you also draw Cube_player_rect. Here's how to solve it:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and Cube_player_rect.x - Cube_Vel > 0:
        Cube_player_rect.x -= Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and Cube_player_rect.x + Cube_Vel < WIDTH  - Cube_player_rect.w:
        Cube_player_rect.x += Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and Cube_player_rect.y - Cube_Vel > 0:
        Cube_player_rect.y -= Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and Cube_player_rect.y + Cube_Vel < HEIGHT  - Cube_player_rect.h:
        Cube_player_rect.y += Cube_Vel


pressed_keys = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if (pressed_keys[0]) and TP_usage > 0:
    TP_usage -= 1
    print(TP_usage)
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    Cube_player_rect.x = mx
    Cube_player_rect.y = my
if (pressed_keys[0]) and TP_usage < 0:
    screen.blit(No_tp_Warning, (400, 400))
```

The font does not draw to you because it has y coordinates outside the image. TP_usage is not updated because you draw an old variable. Try my function for drawing text:

```
def draw_text(text, color, size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, size)
    text = font.render(text, False, color)
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(x, y))
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

This is how you use in main loop:

```
 draw_text(f"TP usages: {TP_usage}", "white", 30, 500, 500)
```

I hope it will help you, Adam